# How to get cursor position in clip editor?

Tags: python, movie-clip-editor

How to get cursor position in clip editor?
I've been searching in context.space_data attributes, and in region, and region_data attributes, no success.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about the Mask mode of the Movie Clip Editor (it's the only 'clip editor' that has a 2D cursor). I've looked through Blender's source code, and it seems that the cursor location is not exposed to Python.

Comment: Yes. In Mask Mode. Thank you for reply. I was assuming there is no ability to get cursor position.It strange, because ability to set 2d cursor is there: bpy.ops.clip.cursor_set(location=(0, 0)).